# use UNION ALL SQL statement with tables from different database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to be able to use UNION ALL SQL statement with tables from two different databases:

- `inventory` and `service2` are the databases
- `prodserial` and `installation2` are the tables
- `serialno` and `cSerialNo` are the fields

I've tried the code below, but nothing is shown in my table.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT inventory.prodserial.serialno 
WHERE trim(prd_sys_code) = '$prd_sys_code' AND 
client_code = '$ship_to' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT service2.installation2.cSerialNo 
WHERE trim(installno) = '$dr_no'");
```

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clauses

Comment: where are the table names? or `from`?

Comment: I tried adding them., still nothing is shown....

Comment: inventory is the database1 and prodserial is the table1   service2 is the database2 and installation2 is the table2..

Comment: Have you checked for errors?  Have you printed the query out to make sure the query is correct?  It is unusual using 2 different databases for a single query.  Are you sure you've designed them properly?  Have you tried each `SELECT` individually to make sure the result is as expected?

Comment: You should be doing something along the lines of `SELECT serialno FROM inventory.prodserial WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT cSerialNo FROM service2.installation2 WHERE...`

Comment: theres no error and yes the query is working individually but when I join them using UNION ALL nothing is shown I think the syntax is wrong because their from two different databases..

Comment: Errors from Mysql aren't printed automatically, you have to call `mysql_error()` to get the error message when `mysql_query()` returns false.

Comment: where should I put the mysql_error? :)

Comment: Along the same lines as Barmar, what is the value of `$fetch`?  What do you mean "nothing is shown"?  Do you mean 0 rows are returned?  Is a false being returned?  Are you even trying to fetch anything after you get a resource from the deprecated `mysql_query`?

Comment: the needed data is now shown in the table., the problem is with the variables., I directly typed the required values for searching...